# How do I setSelection after a text search?

Tags: quill

I am attempting to add a search feature to Quill and want to highlight the text that it finds. I am having trouble getting the range index for the text it finds, and it is likely that I am not using the correct approach.

So far, I get the text using getContents() and can find matches by iterating through the lines. However, I have not been able to find the correct index position for setSelection(). A second issue is that I want the window to scroll to where the selection is found, and it is not scrolling into view.

```
...
myKeyPhrases = ['obvious', 'orange', 'apple'];

var myDelta = editor.getContents();
myDelta.eachLine((line, attributes, i) => {

    mytext = line.filter((op) => typeof op.insert === 'string').map((op) => op.insert).join('');
    mytext = mytext.toLowerCase();

    ndx = isKeyPhraseFound(mytext, myKeyPhrases); 
    if (ndx >= 0){
        // The code finds the matches OK to here.
        // The next 4 lines don't get the correct range and scroll.
        index = i;
        editor.focus();
        editor.setSelection(index, 1, Quill.sources.USER); 
        editor.scrollIntoView();
        return index;
    }
});
```

My desired results would be that a found text match would be selected and that the window would be scrolled so that the selection is displayed. The actual results are that the wrong text is selected and the window is not scrolled to view the selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically there. I suspect your issue is that you're filtering out block elements, which acts similarly to Quill's [`getText`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#gettext) method. According to the docs:

> Non-string content are omitted, so the returned string’s length may be shorter than the editor’s as returned by `getLength`.

This is because non-text elements usually have a length of 1, so for every one of those you omit, your index will drift by 1.

A simple workaround for this is to replace any non-text elements with a newline character, which has length 1, and the added benefit of causing a search across it to fail (unless you let users search with newlines - maybe then you can pick another special character like a control character).

The following method should return a plain-text representation of your Quill contents whose length matches `quill.getLength`, and therefore should be able to be searched using whatever JavaScript text search method you want (eg `indexOf` for simple searches).

```
function textContents() {
  return quill.getContents().ops
    .reduce((text, op) => {
      if (typeof op.insert === 'string') {
        // If the op is a string insertion, just concat
        return text + op.insert;
      } else {
        // Otherwise it's a block. Represent this as a newline,
        // which will preserve the length of 1, and also prevent
        // searches matching across the block
        return text + '\n';
      }
    }, '');

}
```

Here's a rough example: https://codepen.io/alecgibson/pen/GLVzPb